# Unable to add submodules in Git

Tags: git, github

I am unable to push the following sub-module into Github through Git. I'm seeing the following error message. What am I doing wrong?

I followed this steps:

```
cd my_project
git init
git add *
git status
```

Then it shows the messages as :

```
   Changes not staged for commit:
      (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
      (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
      (commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)

        modified:   server/auth (modified content)

    no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

After when i am pushing, my subfolder server/auth is not going to my github repository, Please help me with this i am new to this :
My project structure is as follows:
**Server** as main and **clients**, **resource** and **auth** as submodules, except for "**auth**" everything is commiting.

Comment: Did you make sure to instruct add and commit your changes before you tried pushing?

Comment: yes i followed this link :http://befused.com/git/existing-project-github#comment-138207

Comment: Are you sure? The error message you posted is stating that you did not add or commit your `golive-server/golive-auth` before trying to push. Can you edit your question and include the exact sequence of commands you typed in after you finished editing all your files?

Comment: @ratnesh Hi, can you try `git add .` instead of `git add *`?

Comment: @kucing_terbang , i tried with add .  also but same error message : **changes cannot staged for commit**

Comment: Have you tried `git submodule init` in the root folder of your project(the one with `.gitmodules` file)?

Comment: @halfzebra , when i am doing git submodule init, it is saying as **No submodule mapping found in .gitmodules for path server/auth'**

Comment: @ratnesh If I'm getting it right, your project root is in *server*, just to clarify, are we talking about [Git Submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)? If yes, then you need to locate your `.gitsubmodules` file and initialize them. If no, then sorry for confusion.

Comment: @halfzebra, no inside my main **server** , i have 3 projects : **clients** , **resource** and **auth** , they all run independent of each other,

Answer (score 0):

what's your definition of *Git Submodule*? When I look at your 4 steps it seems to me, that you create a new Git repository with few subfolders but no git submodule?

I you'd want to add git submodules for **clients**, **resource** and **auth** you probably would do something like this:

```
cd my_project
git init
git submodule add <global-path-to-sub-repository> **clients**
git submodule add <global-path-to-sub-repository> **resource**
git submodule add <global-path-to-sub-repository> **auth**
git submodule init
git add *
git status
```